# A geometrical calculation in Fresnel's paper “Memoir on the diffraction of light” 1819

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

It is a geometrical problem which I find difficult to solve reading the Fresnel's paper "Memoir on the diffraction of Light".
According to the figure Fresnel sets $z$ as the distance of the element $nn'$ from the point $M$---- (I suppose $z=nM$)-----, $a=CA$, $b=AB$, $IMA$ is an arc with center $C$, $EMF$ is an arc with center $P$ tangential to the point $M$ with the first arc. Eventually, Fresnel calculate that the distance $nS=\frac{z^2(a+b)}{2ab}$.( I believe that it is an approximation saying $nS≈\frac{z^2(a+b)}{2ab}$)

[image]

(1) How does he find that result?

(2) In my attempt I find that $nS≈\frac{z^2}{2PM}$, pretty close but I cannot find the $PM$ value.Are there any ideas?

(3) Υοu can find the original paper here (page 119): https://archive.org/stream/wavetheoryofligh00crewrich#page/118

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There are also the conditions that the circle $C$ is tangent to the screen (the dashed line) and $PN$ is orthogonal to the screen.

The requirement that $z$ is small implies that $PB$ and $r - b$ are also small.

From $\triangle MCN$, $\sin (\angle MCN / 2) = z/(2 a)$. From $\triangle CPN$,
$$(r + x)^2 = a^2 + (r + a)^2 - 2 a (a + r) \cos \angle MCN.$$
Dropping the $x^2$ term gives
$$r^2 + 2 r x  =
a^2 + (r + a)^2 - 2 a (a + r) \left(
 1 - 2 \left( \frac z {2a} \right)^2 \right), \\
x =  \frac {(a + r) z^2} {2 a r} \sim
\frac {(a + b) z^2} {2 a b} \quad \text{when } z \to 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but how come that nS is orthogonal to the screen? In Fresnel's Figure is shown that n'E is orthogonal and not the nS.

Comment: We assume that the distance $dz = nn'$ is negligible compared to $z$. How the integration of $f(x) dz$ goes through is another question.

Comment: I do find the answer. I post it here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422721/a-geometrical-calculation-in-fresnels-paper-memoir-on-the-diffraction-of-light/423286#423286                                                                                  (because I cannot post it HERE. Thanks for your time!